# How to upload custom boot image to MAAS

Tags: ubuntu, centos, centos7

I successfully installed latest MAAS in ubuntu and i like to upload centos7 to MAAS boot images
I have CentOS-7-x86_64-Everything-1511.iso how can i upload into MAAS.
I searched for uploading custom image to MAAS but i could not find any good way to upload it and some methods are lot of confusion for me.

Please provide a set by step guide to do this

Thank you

Answer (score 0, accepted):

you can build CentOS Images using maas image builder(maas-image-builder) for MAAS.

**Getting a Local Copy of maas-image-builder**

Please use maas-clustercontroler to install  maas-image-builder

bzr branch lp:maas-image-builder

cd maas-image-builder

python setup.py install

aptitude install python-dev

make

**Building CentOS 6 Image**

maas-image-builder -a amd64 -o centos6-amd64-root-tgz centos --edition 6

**Building CentOS 7 Image**

maas-image-builder -a amd64 -o centos7-amd64-root-tgz centos --edition 7

**Getting maas-auth key and logging to API**

maas-region-admin apikey --username=root

maas login maas http://10.1.35.12/MAAS/api/1.0

**Checking for CentOS images  if available boot images**

maas maas boot-resources read | egrep -i  "centos"

**Uploading CentOS6 Image**

maas maas boot-resources create name=centos/centos6 architecture=amd64/generic content@=/root/maas-image-builder/centos6-amd64-root-tgz

**Uploading CentOS7 Image**

maas maas boot-resources create name=centos/centos7 architecture=amd64/generic content@=/root/maas-image-builder/centos7-amd64-root-tgz

Checking for CentOS images   available boot images

maas maas boot-resources read | egrep -i  "centos"

**reference:** https://maas.ubuntu.com/docs/os-support.html

Comment: That does not seem to work for the latest version of MaaS since CentOS images are now maintained in their image repo.  There is very little documentation on how to actually create a custom image.  For example if you need a Redhat or Oracle Linux image you are left with empty promises.